# Image keeps getting deleted

Tags: python, image, tkinter, button, pyautogui

[image]

I'm a new to coding but started since I need to create some software. I have a problem where the images that are attached to a button delete themselves. What I mean is I have 2 images and 2 buttons, I want to press any button and I want images to stack next to each other instead of deleting one. I would appreciate any help!

```
def add_image():
    global my_image
    my_image = PhotoImage(file="Picture1.PNG")
    my_text.image_create(root, command=my_image)

def add_image2():
    global my_image
    my_image = PhotoImage(file="Picture2.PNG")
    my_text.image_create(END, image=my_image)
```

I'm guessing the "END" line makes them delete themselves but I haven't figured what to replace it with.

Comment: You don't need the `global my_image` statements. Since you made the images have the same name, the first image gets overwritten when you create the second one.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin Thank you for the rely! It worked, but the first line of images still move after a couple of clicks, is there any way to make them stay in place? Maybe a column 2x10?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't help you any more unless you provide a [example]. I suggest you read [ask].

Comment: @SylvesterKruin Sorry for not explaining well, i edited the post and provided a link at the top for a picture example. Im trying to code 2 buttons, Button 1= image1, button 2 = image2. My problem is is when the first row gets filled and the images move to the second one, disappearing from the first row. Is there a way to make them intact and not move?

Comment: We can't help you unless you provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to create the two images in global scope:

```py
my_image1 = PhotoImage(file="Picture1.PNG")
my_image2 = PhotoImage(file="Picture2.PNG")

def add_image():
    my_text.image_create(END, image=my_image1)

def add_image2():
    my_text.image_create(END, image=my_image2)
```